# How to get the last value from a child table considering the parent table using Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, element

I have two tables

Sensors

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Measurement;


class Sensor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'sensors';

    public function measurements(){
        return $this->hasMany(Measurement::class);
    }

}
```

and Measurements

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Sensor;


class Measurement extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'measurements';

    public function sensor() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sensor::class);
    }


}
```

There is one Sensor for many Measurments.
What i want to do is to retrieve the last measurements done for each of the sensors
If i have 3 sensors i want the last measurements of the sensor 1, then the last measure of the sensor 2 and so on...

I've tried to do this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Measurement;
use App\Models\Sensor;
use Inertia;


class SensorsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $sensors = Sensor::with( ['measurements' => function ($query) {
            $query->latest('created_at')->first();
        } ] )->get();
        
        return Inertia\Inertia::render('Sensor', compact('sensors'));
    }
```

In the index function what i achieved is to take the last measurements in absolute, but not the last measure for each of the sensors that i have in the database.
How can i achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 'hasOne' relation to get only one record for Senser ...

and the latest() to sort by created_at column

```
class Sensor extends Model
{
  
    public function lastMeasurement(){
        return $this->hasOne(Measurement::class)->latest();
    }

}
```

in your controller you can load it normally

```
  $sensors = Sensor::with( ['lastMeasurement' ] )->get();
```